# Any square matrix is equivalent to zero diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be two square matrices of dimension $n\ge 2$. We say that $A$ and $B$ are **equivalent** if there exist $P$ and $Q$ invertible such that $B=Q^{-1}AP$. Is it true that every square matrix $M$ of dimension $n$ is equivalent to a matrix $D$ where all diagonal elements are zero ? I'm aware of the result that any  square matrix $M$ such that $Trace(M)=0$ is **similar** to a matrix $D$ with zero diagonal elements, and I know that the result is shown by induction. But here I'm asking about $M$ with no restriction on its trace is it equivalent to a matrix with zero diagonal ?

Comment: The answer is yes.  Note that two square matrices are equivalent if and only if they have the same rank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Note that two square matrices are equivalent if and only if they have the same rank.

Let $E_{i,j} = e_i e_j^T$ denote the matrix with zeros except in the $i,j$ entry, where it has a $1$.

We can define $M_0 = 0$, 
$$
M_{k} = \sum_{j=1}^k E_{i,i+1}
$$
for $k = 1,\dots,n-1$, and
$$
M_n = M_{n-1} + E_{n,1}
$$
We note that rank$(M_k) = k$, so that we have selected one element from each class of equivalent matrices.  The conclusion follows.